# Issue while Upgrading fabric from 1.4.4 to 2.2

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

we are able to update peer and orderer components to the latest version but while updating the channel capababilities to fetch the config block,peers are not able to connect with the orderer
Error: could not not connect to ordering service:could not dial endpoint:dial tcp:lookup orderer.example.com on 192.168.0.1:53 :no such host channel=mychannel

[peer logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fN8Ah.png)

Comment: I am trying to upgrade fabric 1.4 network to latest fabric stable version 2.2. In migration steps, I am able to update peer and orderer components to the latest version but while updating the channel capababilities to fetch the config block,peers are not able to connect with the orderer

Error: could not not connect to ordering service:could not dial endpoint:dial tcp:lookup orderer.example.com on 192.168.x.xxxx :no such host channel=mychannel

Answer (score 0):

you'll need to backup the msp and tls folders and load them in your the upgraded containers!
the official documentation mentions that you need to backup the msp but they don't do it.